# Getting application output to a variable python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a python application for executing another application. The application is avrdude.exe and want to read the output of the application to a variable. I tried various methods (subprocess, communicate,check out etc.) but all I'm getting is a blank string. Any ideas?

```
import os 
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['avrdude.exe', '--help'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
output, error = p1.communicate()
print ("hi")
print output
```

Comment: What does `error` contain?

Comment: Are you able to run avrdude.exe from command line? Most probably, it is not setup correctly and throwing an error. What is the value of `p1.returncode`

Comment: Yes. I'm able to run it from command line. No error. I just get nothing when printing 'output'.

Comment: I get 'None' as error. Which means that there are no errors.

Comment: I was wondering if the application needs to stay open or something. Since the application exits if you try from command line. The same should be happening in this case too. Is there any way to kind of freeze an application from exiting but at the same time not hamper its execution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `avrdude.exe` doesn't provide `--help` option, and thus the execution only results error output.

Try to run the exe with the option directly or specify `stderr` to see what you can get from var `error`.

Comment: I was wondering if the application needs to stay open or something. Since the application exits if you try from command line. The same should be happening in this case too. Is there any way to kind of freeze an application from exiting but at the same time not hamper its execution?

Comment: @user3824502, I don't think you need to "freeze" the applcation when you   read from its stdout/stderr. The reason you got nothing from `error`  might be that you didn't specify `stderr` in contructing `Popen`

Comment: How can I do that? I am totally new to python and using it for a small time project.

Comment: @user3824502, it is just likes how you specify `stdout`: subprocess.Popen(..., stderr=subprocess.PIPE, ...)

Comment: @ Lei Shi, I added as you said and the application output that I usually get in the command line is now available in the error variable. I guess that solves my problem, but I would like to get an explanation as to why that is happening. I don't get the logic in that?